# Launching optuna-dashboard in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, optuna

Is there a way to start optuna-dashboard in Google Colaboratory?

When running !optuna-dashboard --port 1234 sqlite:////content/drive/MyDrive/optimization.db the link is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of optuna-dashboard here.
Thank you for trying to use optuna-dashboard.

You need to use `google.colab.output` like below:

```py
    import time
    import threading
    from optuna_dashboard import wsgi
    import optuna
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server


    port = 1234
    storage = optuna.storages.RDBStorage("sqlite:////content/drive/MyDrive/optimization.db")
    app = wsgi(storage)
    httpd = make_server("localhost", port, app)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
    thread.start()
    time.sleep(3) # Wait until the server startup
    
    from google.colab import output
    output.serve_kernel_port_as_window(port, path='/dashboard/')
```

The the link to optuna-dashboard will be printed. Please click to open.

Comment: I have tried this code, and after adjusting the database path I get an URL like:

https://vbe782jnhz-496ff2e9c6d22116-1234-colab.googleusercontent.com/dashboard/

But it gives me a 404 error when I try to open it.