# Human-in-loop optimization Optuna in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, optuna

I am working on a project where I need to run Human-in-loop optimization using Optuna library in Google Colaboratory environment. I would like to use the Optuna Dashboard to monitor the progress of the optimization and interact with it in real time.

I'm using the code from this post to run the Dashboard in Google Colaboratory, but I'm not sure how to implement artifacts in this code.

[Launching optuna-dashboard in Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76033104/launching-optuna-dashboard-in-google-colaboratory)

Can anyone give me some advice on how to accomplish this? What are the best practices for implementing Human-in-loop optimization in Optuna via Google Colaboratory and how can I incorporate artifacts into this process?

Thank you in advance for any help.